# How to avoid useEffect being called multiple times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks, use-effect

Having this code snippet:

```
  const myValue = useSelector(
    (state) => state.myValue,
    shallowEqual
  );
   

  useEffect(() => {
    if (myValue?.apiStatus === 'OK') {
      console.log('run it');
      const cartId = Cookies.get('cartId');
      dispatch(doSomething(cartId));
    }
  }, [myValue, dispatch]);
```

Firstly, the value of `myValue` is undefined so the useEffect doesn't do anything. But once it has value and it contains apiStatus === 'OK', the console log appears tens of times.

Is there a way to make it run only once it this case?

Comment: Does `doSomething` changes `myValue`? If yes, this will run in a loop, since useEffect will run everytime `myValue` changes as it is in the dependency array

Comment: @SinanYaman no, it doesn't change it. the call is made with the same value of it

Comment: Can you create a codesanbox to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0):

i think you must not include dispatch in useEffect  dependcies, then your useeffect fire after myValue change,
so if it still fire multiple time, it must be for setting different values for my Value,
pay attention that if any thing change in myValye, useEffect fire again
another advice might be chaking reducer codes, if a state change in reducer using this maybe causing useEffect fire again:

```
return {...state}
```